# Zeus fails when testing with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, zeus

When I run this command: `rspec spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb`

I get this:

> Finished in 0.54446 seconds
>
> 2 examples, 0 failures
>
> Randomized with seed 6226

It's good.

However when I run this command:

`zeus rspec spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb`

I get this:

> Finished in 0.5356 seconds
>
> 2 examples, 0 failures
>
> Randomized with seed 0

This is not a problem, but then immediately I get also this:

> F.
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) MessagesController POST #create create a message with an HTTP
>   200 status code
>
> ```
>  Failure/Error: post :create, message: "test message"
>  NameError:
>    undefined method `post' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_1:0xb0085d8>
>  # ./spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>  # -e:1:in `<main>'
> ```
>
> Finished in 0.10724 seconds
>   2 examples, 1 failure
>   Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/controllers/messages_controller_spec.rb:9 #
>   MessagesController POST #create create a message with an HTTP 200
>   status code

Comment: Could you post both the controller code and the spec?

Comment: it does not happen in only this test, it does in every test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete a line:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'
```

from your spec_helper.rb.